# How to display when data more than array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

this my program...

```
{
    char name[5];
    cout << "NPM : ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "  name: " << name <<endl;
}
```

make the display name, birth date, with the provisions of each letter can not be more, if more then error. use array function !! how to input data if more array notice error..?

Comment: Why not use a std::string?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not free code writing service

Comment: If you don't want to use `std::string`, consider using `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: i usually using : using namespace std;

Comment: @febriankusuma I'm pretty sure you missed the point of the question. Why are you using a fixed array `char[5]` instead of a resizeable string (i.e., `std::string`) if you'll need to support an unknown max number of characters?

Comment: @febriankusuma I don't see how that relates to the comments, but if you said so, related reading: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: ok thanks all for the reason..

Answer (score 2):

```
{
   char name[5];
   cout << "NPM : ";
   cin.getline(name, 5);
   cout << "   name: " << name << endl;
}
```

Would be possible approach if you HAVE to use char arrays.

The maxlenght for the String itself will be 4 characters long, because `char[4]` will be a Nullbyte ( `'\0'` )

Comment: but... why? it's basic C/C++

Comment: I have no clue, maybe he doesn't know that std::string exists or he's doin it for school...

Comment: Note that the input will be truncated to 4 chars followed by the terminating '\0'

Comment: yeah, but answering such a basic question I don't think it's gonna help him understand the logic behind it..

Comment: ok, thank all for giving answer..

Comment: @IosifMurariu It's basic c++, but not basic C. It's not C at all.

Comment: @IosifMurariu I wouldn't call it C at all

Comment: Sometimes I am surprised how useless answers to useless questions are upvoted.

Comment: yeah, yeah, i know. I wouldn't call it Java either.

Comment: Despite you are wrong about which symbol would be 0, how is this answer related to the question?

Comment: And why am I wrong about the nullbyte?

And its exactly the answer to the question, he wants to know how to prevent a crash if you enter a string larger than 4 characters